# CC section sending one email at a time, and then multiple to the first

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

so the below code in google appscript works fine except for the cc part which I just added, problem described after the code

```
function getSheetID(name){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name)
 var sheetID = ss.getSheetId().toString() 
 return sheetID
}

function DISCHEMEMAILS() {

//NEWEST PRODUCTS CODE
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DISCHEM LINES CHECK").activate();
  
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var shID = getSheetID("DISCHEM LINES CHECK") //Get Sheet ID of sheet name "DISCHEM LINES CHECK"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  
   //EMAIL ADDRESSES CODE FOR PRIMARY EMAIL
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DISCHEM EMAILS").activate();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = "Dear"+" "+row[1]+" "+"here are the classifications."; // Second column
   var Sheets = [{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"}]
   
     //EMAIL ADDRESSES CODE FOR BCC EMAIL
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DISCHEM EMAILS").activate();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRowcc = 3; // First row of data to process
    var numRowscc = 5; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A3:B7
   var dataRangecc = sheet.getRange(startRowcc,1,numRowscc,5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   var datacc = dataRangecc.getValues();
   for (var i2 in datacc) {
    var rowcc = datacc[i2];
    var emailAddresscc = rowcc[0]; // First column
   
   MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: "Classifications",
     cc:emailAddresscc,
    htmlBody: message,
    attachments: Sheets
  });
  };
  };
}
```

is having the effect of sending multiple emails for the cc instead of one with them together. It has three emails in the range, so it sends a email to me and email 1, then me and email 2, then three emails just to me.I want it to send one email, with email 1 and 2 ccd, and me as the primary.

Any ideas on what part of the formula I messed up? After testing some more I think it has to do with the positions of my }, but not sure where they should be

Answer (score 0):

So I did a work around by referencing the cells directly with the emails in it instead of using the same code for the main email. Oh well it works now.

```
//cc emails
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DISCHEM EMAILS").activate();
 var cc1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3').getValue();
  var cc2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A4').getValue();

  //EMAIL ADDRESSES CODE FOR PRIMARY EMAIL
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DISCHEM EMAILS").activate();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = "Dear"+" "+row[1]+" "+"here are the classifications."; // Second column
   var Sheets = [{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"}]
   
   
   MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: "Classifications",
    htmlBody: message,
     cc: cc1 + "," + cc2,
    attachments: Sheets
  });
  };
}
```